# Can't clone because of non existing file?

Tags: svn, mercurial, clone

I have a problem concerning my Mercurial.

Due some circumstances I lost all my Projects in eclipse (which runs on a vm).

Now I wanted to recreate my vm and clone my former projects with hg (since I use it).

Unfortunately now I get an error:

> Data xyz.i@8b8879.... not found

and it stops. 
I don't know what to do, I tried to put in the file in my SVN .. just to clone it (since it's not an important file) but I still get the same error.

So now my question is, is there any way to clone my projects without this file, and how?

Comment: Restore your repository from backup. If it has been corrupted, there's not a lot you can do about it. It depends on the type and extent of corruption, but if cloning doesn't work, you're probably not going to have muck luck besides a full restore.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen: something offtop but curious about how much it can be done when a repository is corrupted: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/236238

Comment: In some cases you can use `hg convert` to strip out missing files, by writing a conversion map that ignores certain files. However that will only work if the data file for that file is missing, not if a revision/changeset file is missing.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen And how could I write a conversion map? The data is really not important, since it's something I can recreat anytime again. But as for the project itself is really important. 
Btw. I didn't understand the first thing you wrote "Restore repository" .. what do you mean by that?

Comment: From backup. You *do* have a backup of your repository, right? As for using `hg convert`, you'll have to consult the help pages. I have only used it once and don't remember the exact method.